# How to convert android color to int

Tags: android-layout

I'm trying to discover a method to convert an Android color to an int value, but I can't do it anyway.

Is there a way to convert Android color to int value?

Comment: what you have try till now?? why you want color in int formate ? tell us so we can find any alter to it. By default android res gives color in int format.

Answer (score -2):

Clarification: the color is currently in an xml format?

If so there appears to be a function just for pulling colors out of xml resources into integer formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

```
int color = res.getColor(R.color.color_name);
```

Where the arguments to getColor are the logical location of the colour, IE...

```
<resources>
<color>
<color_name>
```

Comment: The color is in android.graphics.Color format i need to extract its int value to operate with it

Comment: my hardest googling has me here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Which is showing me that the android.graphics.Color format is an integer already, or a string representing an integer, or a reserved-word string such as "red".

Do you have an example of what you're working with?